# TahDoodle crashes when opening files

Tags: objective-c, macos

My problem: Everything works fine, but when I want to Open a file saved with TahDoodle (the program to learn from big nerd ranches book (*Objective-C Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide*), the program crashes.
I took a look into the "Leaking" instrument and saw many leaks. But i don't know how to fix it.

Here is my code :

**BNRDocument.m**

```
#import "BNRDocument.h"

@implementation BNRDocument

# pragma mark - NSDocument Overrides

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Add your subclass-specific initialization here.
        // If an error occurs here, return nil.
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSString *)windowNibName
{
    // Override returning the nib file name of the document
    // If you need to use a subclass of NSWindowController or if your document supports multiple NSWindowControllers, you should remove this method and override -makeWindowControllers instead.
    return @"BNRDocument";
}

# pragma mark - Actions

- (IBAction)createNewItem:(id)sender
{
    // Falls es noch kein Array gibt, erstellen Sie einfach
    // eines, in dem unsere neue Aufgabe gespeichert wird
    if (!toDoItems) {
        toDoItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    [toDoItems addObject:@"New Item"];

    // -reloadDate aktualisiert die Tabellenansicht und fordert von
    // dataSource (das in diesem Fall zufällig dieses BNRDocument ist)
    // neue Daten zur Darstellung an
    [itemTableView reloadData];

    // -updateChangeCount: teilt der Anwendung mit, ob im Dokument
    // ungespeicherte Änderungen vorhanden sind oder nicht.
    // NSChangeDone kennzeichnet das Dokument als ungespeichert
    [self updateChangeCount:NSChangeDone];
}

# pragma mark - Data Source Methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tv
{
    // Diese Tabellenansicht soll die todoItems darstellen,
    // und somit ist die Zahl der Einträge in der Tabellenansicht
    // gleich der Zahl der Objekte im Array
    return [toDoItems count];
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    // Gibt das Element aus todoItems zurück, das mit der Zelle
    // korrespodiert, die die Tabellenansicht darstellen will
    return [toDoItems objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
   setObjectValue:(id)object
   forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
              row:(NSInteger)row
{
    // Ändert der Benutzer ein To-do-Element in der Tabellenansicht
    // wird das totoItems-Array aktualisiert
    [toDoItems replaceObjectAtIndex:row withObject:object];

    // Dann wird das Dokument gekennzeichnet, es habe
    // ungespeicherte Änderungen
    [self updateChangeCount:NSChangeDone];
}

- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)aController
{
    [super windowControllerDidLoadNib:aController];
    // Add any code here that needs to be executed once the windowController has loaded the document's window.
}

- (NSData *)dataOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
{
    // Diese Methode wird beim Speichern unseres Dokuments aufgerufen
    // Wir sollen dafür sorgen, dass der Aufrufer ein NSData-Objekt bekommt,
    // das unsere Daten umhüllt um sie auf Festplatte schreiben zu können

    // Falls es kein Array gibt, schreibn wir fürs Erste ein leeres Array
    if (!toDoItems) {
        toDoItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }

    // Packt unser toDoItems-Array in ein NS Data-Objekt
    NSData *data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:toDoItems
                                                              format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
                                                             options:0 
                                                               error:outError];

    // Gibt das neu gepackte NSData-Objekt zurück
    return data;
}

- (BOOL)readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
{
    // Diese Methode wird aufgerufen, wenn ein Dokument geladen wird
    // Wir bekommen ein NSData-Objekt und sollen daraus unsere Daten ziehen

    // Extrahiert ToDoItems
    toDoItems = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:data 
                                                          options:NSPropertyListMutableContainers
                                                           format:NULL
                                                            error:outError];

    // Gibt unabhängig vom obigen Aufruf Erfolg oder Misslingen zurück
    return (toDoItems !=nil);
}
@end
```

**BNRDocument.h**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface BNRDocument : NSDocument <NSTableViewDataSource>
{
    NSMutableArray *toDoItems;
    IBOutlet NSTableView *itemTableView;
}

-(IBAction)createNewItem:(id)sender;

@end
```

I red alle code parts 5 times and my girlfriend did 2 times. But everything written in the book is in my application even the fix from this post:
http://forums.bignerdranch.com/viewtopic.php?f=160&t=3494

If you can help me, it would be great! Thank you :)

Best wishes,
Christian

edit:
Ok, I just forgot the console:

```
[Switching to process 746 thread 0x0]
[Switching to process 746 thread 0x3d03]
[Switching to process 746 thread 0x903]
2014-04-27 22:03:55.137 TahDoodle[746:903] *** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (0) beyond bounds (0)
2014-04-27 22:03:55.146 TahDoodle[746:903] *** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (0) beyond bounds (0)
2014-04-27 22:04:02.338 TahDoodle[746:903] *** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (0) beyond bounds (0)
2014-04-27 22:04:02.342 TahDoodle[746:903] *** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (0) beyond bounds (0)
2014-04-27 22:04:06.169 TahDoodle[746:903] *** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (0) beyond bounds (0)
2014-04-27 22:04:06.175 TahDoodle[746:903] *** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (0) beyond bounds (0)
2014-04-27 22:04:09.528 TahDoodle[746:903] *** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (0) beyond bounds (0)
2014-04-27 22:04:09.532 TahDoodle[746:903] *** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (0) beyond bounds (0)
kill
quit
```

But I don't know what that means. But it doesnt seem to be a read error.

edit2: Here is the content of the file that should be loaded:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <string>New Item</string>
    <string>New Item</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

**edit3**

The one and only breakpoint is here:

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    // Gibt das Element aus todoItems zurück, das mit der Zelle
    // korrespodiert, die die Tabellenansicht darstellen will

    return [toDoItems objectAtIndex:row];
```

the tool how to find the exception reasons is very cool. Thanks for it.
I set manual breakpoints at all "returns".

the thing is... the items are loaded. I can see them in the program, but when I click on the window, the program crashes with: EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

When I double click on the saved file, TahDoodle is opened and then it crashes instantly with this message:

```
[...]
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000000000001b
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: objectAtIndex:


Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff89b1108c objc_msgSend_vtable10 + 12
1   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8275aa7c -[NSTableView preparedCellAtColumn:row:] + 323
2   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff82773963 -[NSTableView _drawContentsAtRow:column:withCellFrame:] + 47
3   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff827729fc -[NSTableView drawRow:clipRect:] + 1242
4   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff827722ef -[NSTableView drawRowIndexes:clipRect:] + 369
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff82770c9c -[NSTableView drawRect:] + 1302
6   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff82766cc5 -[NSView _drawRect:clip:] + 3390
7   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff82765938 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 1325
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff82765ca2 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff82765ca2 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff82765ca2 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff82765ca2 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8276400a -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 767
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff82763b2c -[NSThemeFrame _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 254
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff827603de -[NSView _displayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:] + 2683
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff826d9c0e -[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 969
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff826d4aba _handleWindowNeedsDisplay + 678
17  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82449bc5 __NSFireTimer + 114
18  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff832b8bb8 __CFRunLoopRun + 6488
19  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff832b6d8f CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575
20  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff87ac37ee RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 333
21  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff87ac35f3 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 310
22  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff87ac34ac BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 59
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff826a9eb2 _DPSNextEvent + 708
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff826a9801 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 155
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8266f68f -[NSApplication run] + 395
26  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff826683b0 NSApplicationMain + 364
27  BuRo.TahDoodle                  0x00000001000015e4 start + 52

Thread 1:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff89bdbc0a kevent + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff89bddadd _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 154
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff89bdd7b4 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 185
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff89bdd2de _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 252
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff89bdcc08 _pthread_wqthread + 353
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff89bdcaa5 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff89bdca2a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff89bdce3c _pthread_wqthread + 917
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff89bdcaa5 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff89bdca2a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff89bdce3c _pthread_wqthread + 917
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff89bdcaa5 start_wqthread + 13
[...]
```

Comment: Forget the leaks instrument, leaked objects do not cause crashes unless you run out of hard drive space. What output do you see in the console when it crashes?

Comment: see my edits "edit" and "edit2". Thanks for your help.

Comment: That error means there is an array with no items in it, and some code somewhere is trying to access the first item in the array (which does not exist). I don't see the bug anywhere in the code you've posted. Perhaps try setting a breakpoint on "All Exceptions" to find the line of code where it  first fails, then tell us what the stack trace is. Here's how you put a breakpoint on "All" exceptions: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Comment: I updated my post with several information

Comment: grmpf.... I changed my xCode Version from 4.2 to 5.1. Now it works perfectly. :-)

Comment: Ah, yeah you don't want to be running an old version of Xcode. Please post that as an answer to your question, and accept it. Other people will have run into exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my xCode Version from 4.2 to 5.1. Now it works perfectly. :-)